# Как обратиться к конкретной кнопке, созданной в цикле, PyQt6

Tags: python, lambda, сигналы-слоты, калькулятор, pyqt6

Пишу калькулятор на *PyQt6*, создал клаву в цикле из словаря, но уже голову сломал, как обратиться к конкретной кнопке, чтобы ее значение вывести на табло.

Пытался присвоить имя атрибуту и передать в сигнале, однако передает исключительно последнее значение.

Как в событии нажатия конкретной кнопки обратиться к ее атрибуту?

```
from PyQt6.QtCore import QSize
from PyQt6.QtWidgets import QApplication, QWidget, QPushButton, QLCDNumber, QGridLayout
import sys


class Buttn(QPushButton):
    def __init__(self, name):
        super().__init__()
        self.name = name
        self.setText(name)


class MainWindow(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.initUI()

        self.setFixedSize(QSize(265, 370))

    def initUI(self):
        grid = QGridLayout()
        self.setLayout(grid)

        names = ["C", "DEL", "", "*",
                 "1", "2", "3", "/",
                 "4", "5", "6", "+",
                 "7", "8", "9", "-",
                 "+/-", "0", ".", "="]

        positions = [(i, j) for i in range(2, 7) for j in range(4)]

        self.LCD = QLCDNumber()
        self.formula = "0"
        self.LCD.display(self.formula)
        self.LCD.setFixedHeight(40)
        self.LCD.setDigitCount(12)
        self.LCD.setDecMode()
        grid.addWidget(self.LCD, 0, 0, 1, 4)

        self.buttons = []

        for position, name in zip(positions, names):
            if name == '':
                continue
            button = Buttn(name)
            button.setFixedSize(QSize(60, 60))
            button.clicked.connect(lambda: self.the_button_was_clicked(name))
            self.buttons.append(button)
            grid.addWidget(button, *position)
        
        print(name)


        self.move(1200, 550)
        self.setWindowTitle('Calculator')
        self.show()

    def the_button_was_clicked(self, value):
        print("clicked", value)
        self.LCD.display(value)


app = QApplication(sys.argv)

window = MainWindow()
window.show()

app.exec()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Попробуйте так:

```
import sys
'''
from PyQt6.QtCore import QSize
from PyQt6.QtWidgets import QApplication, QWidget, QPushButton, \
    QLCDNumber, QGridLayout
'''
from PyQt5.Qt import *


class Buttn(QPushButton):
    def __init__(self, name):
        super().__init__()
        self.name = name
        self.setText(name)


class MainWindow(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.initUI()
        self.setFixedSize(QSize(265, 370))

    def initUI(self):
        grid = QGridLayout()
        self.setLayout(grid)

        names = ["C", "DEL", "", "*",
                 "1", "2", "3", "/",
                 "4", "5", "6", "+",
                 "7", "8", "9", "-",
                 "+/-", "0", ".", "="]

        positions = [(i, j) for i in range(2, 7) for j in range(4)]

        self.LCD = QLCDNumber()
        self.formula = "0"
        self.LCD.display(self.formula)
        self.LCD.setFixedHeight(40)
        self.LCD.setDigitCount(12)
        self.LCD.setDecMode()
        grid.addWidget(self.LCD, 0, 0, 1, 4)

        self.buttons = []

        for position, name in zip(positions, names):
            if name == '':
                continue
            button = Buttn(name)
            button.setFixedSize(QSize(60, 60))
            
#            button.clicked.connect(lambda : self.the_button_was_clicked(name))
            button.clicked.connect(
# -------------------> vvvvvvvvvvvvv <---------------------------------------- # !!! +++
                lambda ch, name=name: self.the_button_was_clicked(name))            
            
            self.buttons.append(button)
            grid.addWidget(button, *position)
        
#        print(name)


# ???        self.move(1200, 550)
# ???        self.show()

    def the_button_was_clicked(self, value):
        print("clicked", value)
        self.LCD.display(value)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = MainWindow()
    window.setWindowTitle('Calculator')
    window.show()
    app.exec()
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Благорадствую, работает.
Только не очень понял как это работает...
я пробовал такой синтаксис, но он не работал: button.clicked.connect(lambda name=name: self.the_button_was_clicked(name)).
Как добавление одного аргумента, который не используется, меняет все дело?
спасибо

Comment: @Greg Если мой ответ помог вам, то не забудьте пометить как правильный, если вы не знаете, 
как это сделать, проверьте https://ru.stackoverflow.com/tour

Comment: В принципе, я нашел объяснение, касающееся пространства имен и закрытия списка.
Я так понимаю, нужен первый фиктивный аргумент для инициализации, а остальные аргументы передаются без изменений.

Comment: @Greg ch - это от слова checked . https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstractbutton.html#clicked

Comment: clicked has a default checked argument that would override the value of i, so it must be added to the argument list before the keyword value.